# express TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm noob with node and express and when I run my App I have this error. Any solutions? I thing that error is here "app.use(express.static(user));" but I don't sure.

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

// modulos
var home = require('./controllers/home');
var model = require('./models');
var user = require('./controllers/user');

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3005);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/layouts');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(user));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

// rutas
app.use(home);
```

Error

Express
500 TypeError: undefined is not a function

```
at Object.posix.isAbsolute (path.js:479:15)
at posix.normalize (path.js:461:26)
at SendStream.root.SendStream.from (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/gestor/angular/jordi/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:116:16)
at Object.staticMiddleware [as handle] (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/gestor/angular/jordi/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:79:8)
at next (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/gestor/angular/jordi/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
at resume (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/gestor/angular/jordi/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:60:7)
at SendStream.error (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/gestor/angular/jordi/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:73:37)
at SendStream.emit (events.js:107:17)
at SendStream.error (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/gestor/angular/jordi/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:147:51)
at SendStream.onStatError (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/gestor/angular/jordi/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:248:48)
at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/gestor/angular/jordi/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:320:26
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

**controllers/user/index.js**

```
// JavaScript Document
var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express();

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.get('/user/new', function(request, response) {

  response.render('new');

});
```

Comment: What is in `./controllers/user`?

Comment: Serving files, such as images, CSS, JavaScript and other static files is accomplished with the help of a built-in middleware in Express - express.static.

Comment: do you want to serve `user.js` as a static file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of that line(`app.use(express.static(user));`) remove that.

You are defining new app in `controller/user/index.js`.

Those options you have set will not be set to the main app. change the code as below.

main server.js

```
var user = require('./controllers/user')(app);
```

controllers/user/index.js

```
// JavaScript Document
module.exports = function (app){

  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

  app.get('/user/new', function(request, response) {

    response.render('new');

  });
}
```

Comment: `require('./controllers/user')(app);` change that line to before `app.use(home);`

Answer (score 1):

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'controllers/user.js'));
```